# AWS Lambda gives class not found exception for jdbc and org.json JARS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run an AWS Lambda function with the help of eclipse and Maven using AWS tool kit. When I run the project as a Maven test, it successfully runs. But when I export the project as a .jar and upload the jar to AWS Lambda, it gives me the following error trace:

```
Input: ToRupeeDatabase error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Done inserting the data in RDS
```

The code says it runs successfully and the data has been inserted in the RDS, but it is being caught as an exception and the code is crashing.

Code:

```
package com.amazonaws.torupee.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RemoteDataCRON implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

 @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
        
        try {                
            // Exception in the following line when uploaded on AWS Lambda!
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String endPoint = "pathtodatabase?useSSL=false";
            String username = "foor";
            String password = "bar";
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;               
            try {
                Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(endPoint, username, password);                    
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RemoteDataCRON.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            // Some processing here and org.json exception here!
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Database error: " + ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Done inserting the data in RDS");

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return "Hello from Lambda!";
    }

}
```

.pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.amazonaws.torupee</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.256</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is a list of solutions that I tried:

1. I tried adding external JARS for mysql and org.json but that gave me the same errors
2. I tried zipping the project instead of exporting it as a JAR but that gave me ClassNotFoundException on the handler itself
3. I then added the dependencies in the pom file itself as I thought that external JARS were not bundled when making a .jar file
4. I then changed the driver path from "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" to "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" but that still gave me the exception on the console

   Am I doing something wrong or building the Jar incorrectly, is it why Lambda gives me the error when I'm on the management console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by completely ditching the maven approach and did it using a simple java class. You can follow the solution for creating a simple AWS Lambda function in java step by step with this video tutorial I created.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Pm22SJibpQ&t=40s